# AddClass('selected') on menu in shared header

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, submenu

I created a menu in the header.php that will be included in each file, like index.php or contact-us.php.

The only problem, I have now, is to add *selected* to the selected main category in the menu.
This following code basically works until the selected page is loaded, after that, the selected attribute is removed.

Could you please help me to fix this problem?

**HTML**

```
<nav id="navigation">
<ul id="navtop">
    <li class=" first has_navchild" id="Home">
        <a href="index.php">Home</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li class=" first has_navchild">
                <a href="index.php">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class=" last">
                <a href="who-we-are.php">Who we are</a>
            </li>   
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class=" has_navchild" id="Contacts">
        <a href="contacts.php">Contacts</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li class=" first has_navchild">
                <a href="where.php">Where we are</a>
            </li>
            <li class=" last">
                <a href="form.php">Contact form</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#navigation ul li').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        if(($(this).attr("id") === "Home"))
        {
            alert($(this).attr('id')); 
            $("#navigation ul li#Contacts").removeClass("selected");
            $("#navigation ul li#Home").addClass("selected");
        }
        else if($(this).attr("id") === "Contacts")
        {
            alert($(this).attr('id')); 
            $("#navigation ul li#Home").removeClass("selected");
            $("#navigation ul li#Contacts").addClass("selected");
        }
    });    
});
```

Thank you for the help

Comment: When you load new page, no click event happens therefore no element is selected.

Comment: The selected attribute is removed when the page is loaded because the menu is re-loaded. There isn't a way around this unless you can store the selected option on the Server in some way and retrieve it when you load the Header.

Comment: Let your server side script add the correct classes on page load.

Comment: So the best way is to add the menu in each page and not share it in the header.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this method:

```
$(window).load(function() {
                  var url = window.location;
                    $('#navtop a').filter(function() {
                        return this.href == url;
                    }).parents("li").addClass('selected');

            });
```

It checks the current page loaded and automatically adds `'selected'` class to its parent `<li>`

Comment: Fixed. Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 1):

It's normal, your document ready was loaded when all is loaded, after you use an event onclick, but in fact nobody has clicked ... So nothing append.

First use this code for add good class on load :

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if(($(this).attr("id") === "Home"))
        {
            $("#navigation ul li#Home").addClass("selected");
        }
        else if($(this).attr("id") === "Contacts")
        {
            $("#navigation ul li#Contacts").addClass("selected");
        }
    });
```

And add your on click function after ...

```
    $('#navigation ul li').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        if(($(this).attr("id") === "Home"))
        {
            $("#navigation ul li#Contacts").removeClass("selected");
            $("#navigation ul li#Home").addClass("selected");
        }
        else if($(this).attr("id") === "Contacts")
        {
            $("#navigation ul li#Home").removeClass("selected");
            $("#navigation ul li#Contacts").addClass("selected");
        }
    });
```